# Check primality in prime factorization

Tags: java

I have the following code for prime factorization.

```
public static void primeFactors(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i = i+1)
    {     
        while (n%i == 0)
        {
            factors.add(i);
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    if (n>2 ) {
        factors.add(n);
    }
    System.out.println(factors);            
}
```

From a mathematical point of view we have to check if each divisor i is also prime and not only if it is factor. Could anyone explain me (mathematically) why the algorithm still works?

Comment: This is really a math question and not a programming question.  So I shouldn't have answered it.  It probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `i` is not prime; say `i` = `j * k` where `j` and `k` are less than `i`.  That means that when our loop reaches `i`, it has already reached `j` and `k` first.  And after we did the loop for `j`, `n` can no longer be divisible by `j` since we already factored all the `j`'s out of it.  Similarly for `k`.  So when we do the loop for `i`, we know `n` can no longer be divisible by either `j` or `k`; therefore it cannot be divisible by `i`.  So the `while` loop is never executed.  This means we don't need to make a special check for non-prime `i`'s, because nothing will happen anyway.

Comment: Ok i got it! Thank you very much for your answer! Next time i will post on math.stackexchange.com.